# Are there any ways to end a screen recording besides using the drop-down menu at the top of the screen?

Tags: screenshots, android-11

I love the new screen recording feature, but I'm frustrated that every recording has to end with me pulling down the top menu to end it. What I mean is that this action is included in the recording.

Is there any way to end a screen recording other than pulling down that menu and hitting the button? Some kind of shortcut that cuts it off automatically?

(I'm on a pixel 4.)

Comment: I am using Android 11

Comment: Is your device rooted? Are you OK with a paid app, if not rooted?

Comment: Not rooted. Was kinda hoping the OS just had a shortcut built-in....

Comment: No. I have a Pixel 4a and searched a lot. No luck. Rooted means are ruled out. So you have only app options left. This [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.leedroid.shortcutter) looks promising, but screen recorder shortcut is a premium feature